# Rserve connection fails

Tags: java, r, rserve, wps

I am using [WPS4R provided by 52north](https://wiki.52north.org/Geostatistics/WPS4R)

Up to 3 days ago everything was fine and WPS could connect to R by use of Rserve properly but now this connection can not be made. I uninstalled everything, including Apache Tomcat,R and Java JDK, and then installed everything again. the problem still exists. This is the error that I get when I send the request. I am sure the code I used is correct, because it used to work and I did not chang any thing .

This is the error:

```
 An R Connection Error occoured:
    class org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RserveException - eval failed,
    request status: error code: 127 null
```

Comment: Seems like the connection doesn't fails, but the command being evaluated fails. Could you try running the same command on a R shell?

Answer (score 4):

The 127 is a parse error that is coming from R, this is not a workspace issue. If you want to get the error message back. Wrap the call to execute your script/r command with the following to get the error message. I have used this in the past and it works well. See the FAQ for more information.

**http://www.rforge.net/Rserve/faq.html**

```
  c.assign(".tmp.", myCode);
    REXP r = c.parseAndEval("try(eval(parse(text=.tmp.)),silent=TRUE)");
    if (r.inherits("try-error")) System.err.println("Error: "+r.toString())
    else { // success .. }
```